Modify randomizechoice environment
I have this code where \addChoice and \addCorrectChoice do some additional operations in the checkboxes environment.
\let\origcheckboxes\checkboxes
\let\endorigcheckboxes\endcheckboxes

\renewenvironment{checkboxes}
{
  \write\myoutput{\string\hrule}
  \write\myoutput{\string\item}
  \origcheckboxes % Call original checkboxes environment

  \let\origchoice\choice
  \let\origCorrectChoice\CorrectChoice

  \renewcommand{\choice}{%
    \addChoice
    \origchoice% Call the original \choice command
  }
  \renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{%
    \addCorrectChoice
    \origCorrectChoice% Call the original \CorrectChoice command
  }

}
{
  \endorigcheckboxes % Call end of original checkboxes environment
}

I would like to perform a similar modification to the randomizechoice environment (description, exam-randomizechoice.sty). I tried with this following code fragment:
\let\origrandomizechoices\randomizechoices
\let\endorigrandomizechoices\endrandomizechoices

\renewenvironment{randomizechoices}
{
    \write\myoutput{\string\hrule}
    \write\myoutput{\string\item}
    
    \origrandomizechoices % Call original randomizedchoices environment
    
    \let\origchoice\choice
    \let\origCorrectChoice\CorrectChoice
    
    \renewcommand{\choice}{%
        \addChoice
        \origchoice% Call the original \choice command
    }
    \renewcommand{\CorrectChoice}{%
        \addCorrectChoice
        \origCorrectChoice% Call the original \CorrectChoice command
    }
    
}
{
    \endorigrandomizechoices % Call end of original randomizedchoice environment
}

However, \choice and \CorrectChoice appear to be Undefined control sequences (which is surprising because I use them in the randomizechoice environment). Can anyone explain how I can fix this code?
Thanks in advance for your time!

With randomizechoices, each \choice and \CorrectChoice will be called multiple times (environ).  I wonder what the optional argument is for?  You may also have to make changes \AtBeginDocument.
